# Expanding a List Comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have written this line as a single line for loop:

```
p.x, p.y, p.z = [float(s) for s in input('Input X, Y, Z: ').split()]
```

It works fine. But for my own understanding, I tried to expand it as this:

```
p.x, p.y, p.z = input('Input X, Y, Z: ').split()
float(p.x)
float(p.y)
float(p.z)
```

But it throws error (`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'`) whenever I try to do operations on them.

Can someone explain to me what I've done wrong and correct it?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please edit your question to include the full traceback, and the input required to reproduce the problem. See the [mcve] and [ask] pages how to best help us help you.

Comment: That's because you're not reassigning the variables to the float value. Eg: `p.x = float(p.x)`. Alternatively, you can also do `p.x, p.y, p.z = map(float, input('Input X, Y, Z: ').split())`.

Comment: `float` doesn’t modify its parameter, it returns a float number from the parameter. So you need to do e.g. `p.x = float(pi.x)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have said, `float()` doesn't change the values of its input, it returns new values. A quick fix is to `map()` the `float` function onto the split input.

```
class P:
    pass

p = P()

p.x, p.y, p.z = map(float, input('Input X, Y, Z: ').split())

print(p.__dict__)
# Input X, Y, Z: 5.6 3.2 6.7
# {'x': 5.6, 'y': 3.2, 'z': 6.7}
```

You'll probably want to catch exceptions for bad input too.

Comment: Does the ```__dict__``` attribute return values as if they were part of a dictionary? I couldn't find a good reference of it on the internet.

Comment: @Debol yes it returns the objects attributes as a dict. [Here's a bit of doumumentation.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#object.__dict__)